# JSLink for showing the Sum of my list columns will break if one item contain empty value.. it will return "NaN"

Tags: javascript, development, list-view, jslink

I am working on a sharepoint server 2016. and i want to show the sum of my list fields.. so i follow this appraoch:-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30317.sharepoint-2013-displaying-sum-for-calculated-column-in-a-list-view-using-jslink.aspx

which worked well. but if the column i want to show the Sum of have an item which contain empty value, i will get this result `sum=NaN`. so seems it can not do the sum for null values.
now i try modifying the script as follow, to check if the column is null and assign it zero as follow:-

```
function CalculatedFieldViewTemplate(ctx) { 
if(ctx.CurrentItem.Yearof2016MLC != null){
_totalValue += parseFloat((ctx.CurrentItem.Yearof2016MLC).replace(',', ''));
return ctx.CurrentItem.Yearof2016MLC;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}


}
```

but this did not solve the issue. i also try checking the following `typeof ctx.CurrentItem.Yearof2016MLC != "undefined"` but same problem... now the Yearof2016MLC is of type number and which does not have any defualt value and it is optional... and again if there is not any empty value for the Tearof2016MLC every thing will work well. so how i can solve this?

Comment: Yes because you are trying to call `replace()` on `ctx.r`.  What is `ctx.r`?

Comment: @DylanCristy the ctx.r is just a copy of the field ctx.CurrentItem.Total_x0020_billing. as shown on my above script

Comment: No it's not.  `r` is your copy. `ctx.r` is nothing.

Comment: Note that **ctx is a global object**, everyone passes it as a variable, but it is **not**. Objects in JavaScript are always passed by reference. So depending on when this code executes, ctx can be a totally different object. In CSR function calls you can leave the function definition as ``( )`` instead of ``(ctx)`` and all should work the same (because ctx is  global object)

Comment: @DylanCristy sorry it is my fault ..please check my edit to see my updated code..

Answer (score 3):

That TechNet article is just stupid... using hardcoded Column**numbers** to inject content

And the Array.reduce method (since IE9) is a lot easier to calculate

I whipped this up real quick.. ofcourse with [Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar), so this is the complete MDS safe CSR file:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function sumColumn(columnName){
    var rows=ctx.ListData.Row; // global ctx!!
    var sum=rows.reduce(function(sums,item){  // loop over all Array items
        var value=item[columnName];
        return sums + (value ? Number(value) : 0); // calculate sums, does not take care of strings!
    },0); // sums starts at 0
    var id="Sum"+columnName; // unique id so multiple columns can be summed
    var sumDIV=document.getElementById(id);
    if(!sumDIV){ // if no Sum div exist
      sumDIV=document.createElement('DIV');
      sumDIV.id=id;
      // find column
      var header=document.querySelector("[id*='thead-WPQ1'] div[name='"+columnName+"']");
      header.appendChild(sumDIV);
    }
    sumDIV.innerHTML=String.format("<B>Sum: {0}</B>",sum);
  }

  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {},
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) { 
        sumColumn('MonthSpan');   // USE INTERNAL FIELD NAME!
      },
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/sumcalculated.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

---

See last Column, just to proof it works, 
I picked a Custom List I had open so no fancy sum:

[image]

### Paging

This only gets you the Sum in the View

If you need the sum of all Items you

- Need code behind/workflow to calculated a Sum for every new Item added

OR

- Need to read **all** Items using JSOM or REST code, then use above code to proces the `rows` you get with `data.d.results`

Comment: so now how i need to reference Cisar inside my sharepoint sites? is there a script i need to reference ?

Comment: also i am not sure what i need to provide inside the sumcalculated.js ???can you adivce on this further ?

Comment: [Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar) is a Chrome Extensions that adds an editor (just like you are now using Notepad or Visual Studio) to the F12 Dev tools, It creates the JS files you are now creating by hand, sets the JSLinks you are now setting by hand. So everything is the same as you are now doing by hand, only more automated. The only thing to change in the above code is the **internal** fieldname of the **View** field you want to Sum

Comment: and i have noted a critical bug in the Technet article,, as the approach proposed will only sum the fields per page and not per list.. so if i have a list which contain 150 items,, and i chose to display 30 items per page,, then the sum will be for the current 30 items and not for the whole 150 items.. so i am not sure if this is fixed inside your code?

Comment: second question , i am still not sure what i need to provide inside the sumcalculated.js ???

Comment: It is not a bug, Sum only can work on the displayed **View** Items, as it has no awareness at all there are more Items. Same applies when you do the **standard SharePoint View Sum/Total** on regular Number Fields. SharePoint is **not** a relational Database so a sum over all Items takes some serious coding & workflows.. that is out of the scope of this (View) Sum answer. Since you don't know how to use this code, I fear programming a Sum is beyond your skill level.

Comment: but instead of judging other skills,, you need to review ur skills also... now if you chose to show the total of a non-calcualted column from "edit view">> "under Totals" >> "select a column">>"sum".. then the sum will be for the whole list items and not just for the current paging.... but the limitation is that the list view Total section does not allow selecting calculated columns.. but saying that "..Same applies when you do the standard SharePoint View Sum/Total on regular Number Fields ..." is totally wrong.. so i think this question is beyond your skill level also !!!

Comment: Hi there, I think both of you need to focus on the problem and lay of the attitude. I'm sure Danny is just trying to help you John, and you have to try to take his advice. And Danny, I think John wants your help

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman now i tried your script and it show the sum value.. but still the Sum will be only for the items inside the current page. so doing paging will change the Sum value.. while i want the Sum to be for all the list view items (the items which are related to the current list view) regardless of the page i am in .. same as the behavioure for the built-in Sum under the list view Total section.. can you adivce on this please?

Comment: As I have said and Dylan tried to explain. Then you have to add code and process the **whole** list yourself (REST/JSOM) The ListView only fills the Global ctx with the relevant Items (standard Sharepoint behaviour) [this is the last response you get from me]

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman ya i know but on the other question u mentioned that the CSR you provided should do the work for me !! that why i am asking ..... you mentioned this "My CSR example seems to do what you want. I can't force it on you".. so not sure what you exactly mean ?

Comment: [no, I said last response]

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman as you wish.. i can not force you to answer... and thanks for your code anyway..

Comment: @johnG But Danny DID give you an answer: you can't accomplish what you need with straight JSLinks.  You need to use JSOM or REST.  If you are having trouble with that as well, then revise or ask a new question.